# Updated omnifaces jar, now it says that my converters are ambiguous

Tags: jsf, converters, cdi, omnifaces

So I was running an old version of omnifaces - 1.8.3, now I updated to the latest 2.6.3 and I get some pretty odd exception when I try to login. The problem is I really don't know how to properly debug a .xthml jsf

Exception I am getting:

```
2017-07-10T16:32:46.631+0300|Warning: StandardWrapperValve[Faces Servlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet Faces Servlet threw exception
org.jboss.weld.exceptions.AmbiguousResolutionException: WELD-001318: Cannot resolve an ambiguous dependency between: 
  - Managed Bean [class kamelon.ui.convertors.LoginConverter] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Managed Bean [class kamelon.ui.convertors.IdentityHashCodeConverter] with qualifiers [@Any @Default],
  - Managed Bean [class kamelon.ui.convertors.IdentifiableConvertor] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]
    at org.jboss.weld.manager.BeanManagerImpl.resolve(BeanManagerImpl.java:1235)
    at org.jboss.weld.util.ForwardingBeanManager.resolve(ForwardingBeanManager.java:91)
    at org.jboss.weld.bean.builtin.BeanManagerProxy.resolve(BeanManagerProxy.java:115)
    at org.omnifaces.util.BeansLocal.resolve(BeansLocal.java:77)
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.converter.ConverterManager.createConverter(ConverterManager.java:122)
    at org.omnifaces.cdi.converter.ConverterManager$Proxy$_$$_WeldClientProxy.createConverter(Unknown Source)
    at org.omnifaces.application.OmniApplication.createConverter(OmniApplication.java:82)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ValueHolderRule$LiteralConverterMetadata.applyMetadata(ValueHolderRule.java:85)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.MetadataImpl.applyMetadata(MetadataImpl.java:81)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.MetaTagHandler.setAttributes(MetaTagHandler.java:129)
    at javax.faces.view.facelets.DelegatingMetaTagHandler.setAttributes(DelegatingMetaTagHandler.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.doNewComponentActions(ComponentTagHandlerDelegateImpl.java:491)
....
```

I have specified < p:(component)>< f:converter>< /p:(component)> in many files and I don't know if I should switch them to < p:(component) converter=""/> now or if I should add more (and where?) for the new version.

Don't know what is the problem with the new version, can somebody help?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have the same problem with plain jsf components? And this is not an xhtml problem but a bean one. Do you by any chance inject interfaces spmewhere?

Comment: Put `@Specializes` on converter subclasses which extends another converter and retry (see also http://showcase.omnifaces.org/cdi/FacesConverter). If that still fails tell more about the server/JSF/CDI versions used.

Comment: I fixed it and posted the solution below, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

This will happen if you have a `@FacesConverter` which extends an existing `@FacesConverter` instead of directly implementing the `Converter` interface.

For example,

```
@FacesConverter("identifiableConverter")
public class IdentifiableConvertor implements Converter {}
```

```
@FacesConverter("identityHashCodeConverter")
public class IdentityHashCodeConverter extends IdentifiableConvertor {}
```

```
@FacesConverter("loginConverter")
public class LoginConverter extends IdentityHashCodeConverter {}
```

This way, when you ask CDI for an instance of `IdentifiableConvertor`, CDI doesn't know which one exactly you mean. It could be as good `IdentityHashCodeConverter` or `LoginConverter` because they are both assignable to a `IdentifiableConvertor` field. This is ambiguous.

This can be solved by putting `@Specializes` on the subclasses.

```
@FacesConverter("identifiableConverter")
public class IdentifiableConvertor implements Converter {}
```

```
@FacesConverter("identityHashCodeConverter")
@Specializes
public class IdentityHashCodeConverter extends IdentifiableConvertor {}
```

```
@FacesConverter("loginConverter")
@Specializes
public class LoginConverter extends IdentityHashCodeConverter {}
```

This way CDI knows that `IdentityHashCodeConverter` should only be assigned to a `IdentityHashCodeConverter` field and the `LoginConverter` should only be assigned to a `LoginConverter` field. When you now ask for `IdentifiableConvertor`, CDI knows it can't be the `IdentityHashCodeConverter` or `IdentityHashCodeConverter` and thus only the `IdentifiableConvertor` remains available, without ambiguity.

Alternatively, you can also drop the superclass and implement the bare `Converter` interface directly. But this is not [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: CDI definition failure:WELD-000047: Specializing bean must extend another bean:  Managed Bean [class kamelon.ui.convertors.IdentifiableConvertor] with qualifiers [@Any @Default]

I'm extending org.omnifaces.converter.SelectItemsConverter;

Comment: How does your beans.xml look like? With `bean-discovery-mode="all"`?

Comment: I can't have it since I'm running CDI 1.0

Comment: This is unexpected. OmniFaces 2.x is targeted at JSF 2.2+ and CDI 1.1+.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a Convertor extending org.omnifaces.converter.SelectItemsConverter gives that exception, implementing javax.faces.convert.Converter fixed it for me. Don't know why is it so...